# getting a value from a form and printing the checked values only

Tags: php, html, forms, web

i need to get the check box value checked by a user and print them.

what currently i am doing is below but i am not sure what to write a script for action in the form

```
<form id="shop" method="POST" action="">
  <section id="latest" class="last clear">
    <article class="one_quarter">
      <figure><img src="images/g1.jpg" width="215" height="100" alt="">
        <figcaption>
          Value : $100 <br />
          Price : $75.00
          <input type="checkbox" name="one" />
          <br />
          <footer class="more"><a href="#">Read More &raquo;</a></footer>
        </figcaption>
      </figure>
    </article>
    <article class="one_quarter">
      <figure><img src="images/g2.jpg" width="215" height="100" alt="">
        <figcaption>
           Value : $100 <br />
          Price : $82.00
          <input type="checkbox" name="two" />
          <br />
          <footer class="more"><a href="#">Read More &raquo;</a></footer>
        </figcaption>
      </figure>
    </article>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

create a file like "result.php" in the same directory

make the action of the for "result.php"

result.php:

```
if(isset($_POST["one"])){
    echo $_POST["one"];
}
 if(isset($_POST["two"])){
    echo $_POST["two"];
}
```

Comment: the way you are suggesting will let user select only one answer at the time with radio buttons secondly this code echo $_POST["one"];
echo $_POST["two"];   will print just the values of both! i need only the value of the checked one

Comment: okay got it now, edited code, now it will print both if Both are checked, 1 if 1 is checked, and nothing if none of them is checked

Comment: it worked , but it said on! instead of giving name of the field or the some kind of name i gave it! it just says on!

Comment: try adding a name to your input like:  <input type="checkbox" name="one" value="one" /> or  <input type="checkbox" name="one" value="two" />